# Unable to register rocket.chat service in ubuntu windows subsytem

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rocket.chat

I'm trying to install rocket.chat server on my machine running Ubuntu subsytem on Windows 10.

Followed all the steps mentioned on 
https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/

Mongodb service is working fine but rocketchat service is not working.

Tried `service --status-all` which is not listing the mentioned service.